# Hibernate infinite loop recursion in many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, recursion, many-to-many

I want to create bidirectional student-discipline relation. Anything works fine until I've enrolled user to discipline. Now I'm getting infinite recursion.

Classes looks like this:

```
//Student.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @NotNull
    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "students_disciplines", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DISCIPLINE_ID"))
    @JsonSerialize(using = NestedDisciplineSetSerializer.class)
    private Set<Discipline> disciplines = new HashSet<>();
    //Getters, Setters
}
//NestedDisciplineSetSerializer.java
public class NestedDisciplineSetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Set<Discipline>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Set<Discipline> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider p) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        for (Discipline s : value) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("name", s.getName());
            jgen.writeNumberField("id", s.getId());
            jgen.writeBooleanField("recommended", s.isRecommended());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
//Discipline.java
@Entity`enter code here`
@Table(name = "disciplines")
public class Discipline {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DISCIPLINE_ID")
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private int credits;
    private String annotation;
    private boolean recommended;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "disciplines", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonSerialize(using = NestedStudentSetSerializer.class)
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
    //Getters, Setters
}
//NestedStudentSetSerializer.java
public class NestedStudentSetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Set<Student>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Set<Student> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider p) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        for (Student s : value) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("name", s.getName());
            jgen.writeStringField("id", s.getId());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

Error appears to be while loading Set after `Student s = sDao.findOne(id);`

Tried to search here, but was not able to find right solution. Anything made the same result.

[Error log](http://pastebin.com/JZ6Xd68N)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
>       at truelecter.practproekt.entity.**Discipline.hashCode**(Discipline.java:31)
>   ~[classes/:na]
>       at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
>       at ... org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
>       at truelecter.practproekt.entity.**Student.hashCode**(Student.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
>       at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344) ~

I have the impression that the `hashcode()` method implementations for `Discipline` and `Student` entities use both entities. 
Maybe am I wrong, it is not very clear in the stacktrace.
How have you defined `equals()` and  `hashcode()` methods for your entities ?
Suppose entity `A` and entity `B` with a bidirectional relationship.
If `equals()/hashcode()` implementation of entity `A`
invokes `equals()/hashcode()` on the entity `B` field that itself invokes `equals()/hashcode()` on the entity `A` field, you have a cycle.
Whereas your error.

Besides, even if you cut the cycle by ensuring that only one of both refers the other in `equals()/hashcode()/toString()`, you should invoke `equals()/hashcode()/toString` methods of the entity relationships with cautious.
It may have a real impact on the performance. If the Hibernate session is opened, it may indeed execute queries that you don't expect to.

Comment: Thanks for answer, problem was in lombok library which I've used to simplify generation of getters and setters. It's @Data annotation generated hashCode() method for both entities which created a loop.

Comment: after implementing equals() and hashcode() and removing the reference to one another, it worked!!! and i learned something, tks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Both of the sides have a Eager fetch type. Which means that for each Student you load, Hibernate will load every Discipline related, and for each Discipline, it will load its Students. This is your loop. You could change the fetch type of one side (better both), for `FetchType.LAZY`. Doing that, the discipline of a student will be load just when you access the list.