# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError with root cause

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Getting this error when jpa tries to fetch the object from database.

Error : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

**UserController**
In this the getUsers method doesn't work and caused error

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public MessageDto addUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto)
    {
        log.info("Post call have been received at user/add with DTO " + userDto);
                                             //Set<UserRoleDomain>
        UserDomain userDomain = userService.mapUserDtoToDomain(userDto);
        return userService.add(userDomain, roleService.add(userDomain));
    }

    @GetMapping("/get/{userName}")
    public UserDto getUsers(@PathVariable("userName") String userName)
    {
        log.info("Get call have been received at user/get/ "+userName);
        return userService.getById(userName);
    }

}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    public MessageDto add(UserDomain userDomain , Set<UserRoleDomain> userRoles)
    {
            // UserDomain userDomain = mapUserDtoToDomain(userDto);
            if( userRepository.findByUserName(userDomain.getUserName())!=null) // causing error
            {
                String responseMessage = "User is already register with name ! "+userDomain.getUserName();
                MessageDto messageDto = new MessageDto(responseMessage);
                log.info(responseMessage);
                return messageDto;
            }
            else {

                for (UserRoleDomain userRoleDomain: userRoles) {
                    System.out.println("result : "+userRoleDomain.getRoleDomain());
                    roleRepository.save(userRoleDomain.getRoleDomain());
                }

                userDomain.getUserRoleDomains().addAll(userRoles);
                userRepository.save(userDomain);
                String responseMessage = "User has been added with Id " + userDomain.getUserId();
                MessageDto messageDto = new MessageDto(responseMessage);
                log.info(responseMessage);
                return messageDto;
            }
    }

    public UserDto getById(String userName)
    {
       UserDomain userDomain =  userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
       return mapUserDomainToDto(userDomain);
    }

    public UserDomain mapUserDtoToDomain(UserDto userDto)
    {
        return objectMapper.convertValue(userDto , UserDomain.class);
    }

    public UserDto mapUserDomainToDto(UserDomain userDomain)
    {
        return objectMapper.convertValue(userDomain , UserDto.class);
    }

}
```

**This is my terminal**

```
2021-07-31 13:57:50.549  WARN 13691 --- [nio-8881-exec-1] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@17f80723<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@763024380 wrapping Result set representing update count of -1>
2021-07-31 13:57:50.549  WARN 13691 --- [nio-8881-exec-1] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@38b516d2<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1651373951 wrapping Result set representing update count of -1>
2021-07-31 13:57:50.558 ERROR 13691 --- [nio-8881-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1535) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:143) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:674) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:541) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1221) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:695) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.RoleDomain.hashCode(RoleDomain.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.UserRoleDomain.hashCode(UserRoleDomain.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.RoleDomain.hashCode(RoleDomain.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.UserRoleDomain.hashCode(UserRoleDomain.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.RoleDomain.hashCode(RoleDomain.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.UserRoleDomain.hashCode(UserRoleDomain.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.RoleDomain.hashCode(RoleDomain.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.UserRoleDomain.hashCode(UserRoleDomain.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.RoleDomain.hashCode(RoleDomain.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.UserRoleDomain.hashCode(UserRoleDomain.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: It was working fine but i dont know what happened now

Comment: you have one or more relation is null  you have field in database dont has forigen key check the filed in database or delete the relation result into dto

Comment: Show us `RoleDomain.hashCode`

Comment: in dto you have object has null when transfer from entity to dto

Comment: Also show `UserRoleDomain.hashCode`

Comment: I bet your `RoleDomain` have field with type `UserRoleDomain` and vice versa. Both of those classes use its corresponding field in `hashCode` calculation.

Comment: It's a good thing you came to Stack Overflow and reported this error to us. ;)

Back on topic- a Stack overflow error in java means you've called too many methods without returning and your call stack has become too large. It can happen when your code is in an infinite loop calling a method over and over.

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40694643/4425643

Comment: You can check the other classes of my application here for having a clear understanding about the issue  https://github.com/iqbalrohail/Exam-portal-backend

Comment: The problem was with @Data annotation which I were using earlier ..

Comment: It's recommended to post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking for help. Furthermore, please place the contents of `RoleDomain.java` into your question since it was required to understand the problem and was part of the solution.

Answer (score 8):

A Stack Overflow error happens when your code has called too many methods without returning and there are too many methods in the stack, causing it to overflow. This commonly happens when you have an infinite loop where a method calls itself repeatedly.

There is a loop happening in your `hashCode` method in `com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.UserRoleDomain` which calls `com.examportal.examportalapi.domain.RoleDomain.hashCode`.

You have the [@Data lombok annotation](https://github.com/iqbalrohail/Exam-portal-backend/blob/43346cc6f6ff28e9c4df54fa616d8990a9c1358b/src/main/java/com/examportal/examportalapi/domain/RoleDomain.java) in these two classes. Replace the @Data annotation with *just* the features you need in the classes.
@Data generates hashCode methods that cause your problem. See the documentation: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment: have a look at my domain package and other classes here https://github.com/iqbalrohail/Exam-portal-backend

Comment: Hey I took a look and updated my answer, let me know if it's not resolved. @Rohail Iqbal

Comment: yes i changed Data annotations in my whole code to simple Lombok annotations and it works for me  ie; Setter- -Getter-- AllArgsConstructor --NoArgsConstructor-- ToString

Comment: This article (https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)  helps me understanding why it is not good to use @Data , thanks CausingUnderflowsEverywhere

Comment: No problem @RohailIqbal remember to up vote helpful answers and down vote not helpful ones and choose an answer to mark as the solution before you go.

Comment: I am a newbie on stack overflow so need some reputation ..if you find the question useful your up vote for the question would be appreciated .

Comment: I will leave some feedback.

Answer (score 8):

Changed **@Data** annotation with the following Lombok annotations and it worked for me

@Setter

@Getter

@AllArgsConstructor

@NoArgsConstructor

@ToString

@Entity

Comment: use @Data in lombok

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem and solved this problem with `@Data` annotation only so that you can solve this problem only `@Data` annotation as well. you have add `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` and `@ToString.Exclude` in your entities.

Answer (score 0):

may be useful.
Today I lost a lot of time because i tried to print a List object. It was calling implicitely toString(), but the error came from Unit tests and it was not pointing directly to the class with the problem

```
List<ArticoliDto> articoli = articoliService.SelByDescrizione("blabla"); //return a List<xxx>
logger.info("Trovati articoli: " + articoli); //this causes the error!!
```

The exception was (partially):

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:199)
    at com.xantrix.webapp.UnitTest.ControllerTest.SelectArtTest.listArtByDesc(SelectArtTest.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. after debugging found out that there was a cycle in my code. after fixing that the error was solved. Please, check for the cycle in your code too. maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

when I upgraded the project I did face the same issue, adding "implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0'" in build.gradle helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It will be great to have the code of the classes **UserDomain** and **RoleDomain**.

I've noticed a potential dependency between UserDomain and RoleDomain. Currently, when saving a UserDomain, it appears to be attempting manual role creation.

I suggest exploring the possibility of eliminating the manual role creation code. Instead, configure the system to handle role creation automatically through the ORM during the process of saving a UserDomain.